# How to not do Block Quotes in Discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to ***not*** do Block Quotes?

I want to get `> Text` without Block Quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a double `\` before the greater-than sign.

Example:

```js
message.channel.send("\\> Hello!");
```